# Solving proplem by Laplace transform

Tags: integral-transforms

I want to solve these ODE's by Laplace transformation and graph it

dx1/dt = 38/1180 x3(t) + (1 + sin⁡(t)) -  38/2900 x1(t), x1(0) = 0
dx2/dt = 18/2900 x1(t) -  18/850 x2(t), x2(0) = 0
dx3/dt = 20/2900 x1(t) + 18/850 x2(t) - 38/1180 x3(t), x3(0) = 0

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the derivatives are with respect to `t` rather than `y`

```
eqns =
  x1'[t] == 38/1180 x3[t] + (1 + Sin[t]) - 38/2900 x1[t] &&
   x2'[t] == 18/2900 x1[t] - 18/850 x2[t] &&
   x3'[t] == 20/2900 x1[t] + 18/850 x2[t] - 38/1180 x3[t] &&
   x1[0] == 0 && x2[0] == 0 && x3[0] == 0;

sol = Simplify[
  InverseLaplaceTransform[#, s, 
     t] & /@
   (Solve[LaplaceTransform[#, t, s] & /@ eqns[[1 ;; 3]],
       LaplaceTransform[#, t, s] & /@
        {x1[t], x2[t], 
         x3[t]}][[1]] /.
     {x1[0] -> 0, x2[0] -> 0, x3[0] -> 0})]

(* {x1[t] -> 18486080/1433151 + (10 t)/17 - (
   290 (18265063653563 Cos[t] - 239228833655 Sin[t]))/
   5298953696690809 - (25 E^(-9669 t/
       290870) (3614626784946938600198 Sqrt[797794]
          Cos[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/727175] - 
        114858249761272146274673 Sin[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/
          727175]))/(7594200789366129609159 Sqrt[797794]), 
 x2[t] -> -(3553945/814929) + (5 t)/29 - (
   765 (1472324257 Cos[t] + 42945441730 Sin[t]))/
   5298953696690809 + (25 E^(-9669 t/
       290870) (753324314919306329902 Sqrt[797794]
          Cos[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/727175] - 
        444608127770297305335495 Sin[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/
          727175]))/(4318271037090544287561 Sqrt[797794]), 
 x3[t] -> 118 (-(2654947/41561379) + t/
     493 + (-8126348313 Cos[t] - 309517786750 Sin[t])/
     5298953696690809 + (E^(-9669 t/
         290870) (14068778962410295885750 Cos[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/727175] + 
          2049165812839859145142450 Sqrt[2/398897]
            Sin[(6 Sqrt[797794] t)/727175]))/220231822891617758665611)} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
eqns[[1 ;; 3]] /. sol /. D[sol, t] // Simplify

(* True *)

{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. sol /. t -> 0

(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: thank you very much, yeah yeah its t not y

Answer (score 1):

You can try to optimize this more. But this should get you started

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, x3, t];
ode1 = x1'[t] == 38/1180 x3[t] + (1 + Sin[t]) - 38/2900 x1[t]
ic1 = x1[0] -> 0
ode2 = x2'[t] == 18/2900 x1[t] - 18/850 x2[t]
ic2 = x2[0] -> 0 
ode3 = x3'[t] == 18/2900 x1[t] - 18/850 x2[t]
ic3 = x3[0] -> 0 
repl = {LaplaceTransform[x1[t], t, s] -> X1[s], 
  LaplaceTransform[x2[t], t, s] -> X2[s], 
  LaplaceTransform[x3[t], t, s] -> X3[s]}


lap1 = (LaplaceTransform[ode1, t, s] /. ic1) /. repl
lap2 = (LaplaceTransform[ode2, t, s] /. ic2) /. repl
lap3 = (LaplaceTransform[ode3, t, s] /. ic3) /. repl
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can solve for `X1[s],X2[s],X3[s]` and then inverse Laplace each and plot the solutions

```
sol = First@Solve[{lap1, lap2, lap3}, {X1[s], X2[s], X3[s]}]
x1Sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[X1[s] /. sol, s, t];
x2Sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[X2[s] /. sol, s, t];
x3Sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[X3[s] /. sol, s, t];

Plot[x1Sol, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x2Sol, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x3Sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, your `dx1/dy, dx2/dy, dx3/dy` all should be written as `dx1/dt, dx2/dt, dx3/dt`

Comment: thank you , sorry for this mistake

Comment: can I ask you another question please, how I can to apply this, I don't know how to use this program and  I need these three lines in the same graph 
thank you again

Comment: @alaa to plot them in same plot, use `Plot[{x1Sol, x2Sol, x3Sol}, {t, 0, 0.4}]` but then you will not be able to see `x2` and `x3` well, since the scale is much different, that is why I plotted them in separate plots.

Comment: thanks a lot, Nasser

Comment: As @Nasser says, the plot scales are quite different but if you scale the first, you can put them on the same graph doing something like this: 
    Plot[{x1Sol/30, x2Sol, x3Sol}, {t, 0, 10},  PlotLegends -> {"x1Sol/30", "x2Sol","x3Sol"}]